# swift 3: Application tried to present modally an active controller

Tags: ios, xcode, swift

Вызываю Alert из другого алерта:

```
let alert = UIAlertController(title: "Добавление", message: "", preferredStyle: UIAlertControllerStyle.actionSheet)
    alert.addAction(UIAlertAction(title: "Новая запись", style: UIAlertActionStyle.default, handler: { (action) in
        alert.dismiss(animated: true, completion: nil)
        self.addItem()
    }))

func addItem() {
    let alert2 = UIAlertController(title: "Куда?", message: "", preferredStyle: UIAlertControllerStyle.actionSheet)
    for i in self.sections {
        alert2.addAction(UIAlertAction(title: "\(i.station!)", style: UIAlertActionStyle.default, handler: { (action) in
            alert2.dismiss(animated: true, completion: nil)
            print(i)
        }))
        self.present(alert2, animated: true, completion: nil)
    }
}
```

Как все же правильно вызвать второй Alert?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

У экземпляра класса UIAlertController не нужно вызывать dismiss.

Вот рабочий код, который выполняет задачу.

```
let addAlert = UIAlertController(title: "Добавление", message: "", preferredStyle: .actionSheet)
let whereAlert = UIAlertController(title: "Куда?", message: "", preferredStyle: .actionSheet)

let newEntryAction = UIAlertAction(title: "Новая запись", style: .default) { _ in
    self.present(whereAlert, animated: true)
}
for station in 0..<10 {
    let stationAction = UIAlertAction(title: "\(station)", style: .default) { _ in
        print(station)
    }
    whereAlert.addAction(stationAction)
}

addAlert.addAction(newEntryAction)
present(addAlert, animated: true)
```